# SyncFusion, Bad PDF Format, Inverted Color on Inputs

Tags: vb.net, pdf, acrobat, pdfsharp, syncfusion

So the state publishes PDF files for us to download. However these files only look right in Adobe Acrobat. When I try to open them in PDFSharp or SyncFusion it fails with the error that there are no pages. When I have PDFSharp or SyncFusion create a new file from the pages in the PDF the result is the following;

[image: PDF Weirdness]

However if I save this document as an archive-able PDF/A in Adobe Acrobat Pro, the file straightens out and both PDFSharp and SyncFusion have no problems printing and viewing the resulting PDF file. I can't get SyncFusion to re-save the document as a PDF/A and have it fix like with Adobe.

What could cause this issue?

Edit: The PDF file says it was created by an Elixir program which converts open document formats to PDF. Possibly Librex.

Comment: Hi Kayot,


Can you please provide the PDF document you have used for reproducing the issue using Syncfusion library? 

It will be helpful for us to analyze more and assist you better.


Regards,
Deepak G

Comment: I wish I could. It's a confidential document from the state with socials and full names. SyncFusion's bug system basically says they won't accept this document due to that.